# Converting ipv6 address to string and vice versa using boost library

Tags: ipv6

GIven a IPV6 address wanto convert it to string and given string want to convert to IPV6 address using the standard boost library.
What are the api's i can use

Answer (score 1):

Use inet_ntop() to convert IPv6 addresses from binary to text form [(see here)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html)

Use inet_pton() to convert IPv6 addresses from text to binary form [(see here)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html)